# TaskAsync no se ejecuta

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Estoy intentando llenar un Spinner al clickear en un botón. que la función se ejecute mediante un AsyncTask para no ralentizar la aplicación.

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sigeapp;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<String> arrList_obras;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapter_obras;
private Spinner spinner_obras;
private Button button;

CONEXIONES conexiones = new CONEXIONES();
private MitareaAsincrona mitarea;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spinner_obras = findViewById(R.id.spinner_prueba);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mitarea = new MitareaAsincrona();
            mitarea.execute();
        }
    });

}

private void tareaLarga()
{
    arrList_obras = conexiones.SELECT("SELECT * FROM OBRAS", getApplicationContext(), 3);
    arrAdapter_obras = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_drawable, arrList_obras);
    spinner_obras.setAdapter(arrAdapter_obras);

}


private class MitareaAsincrona extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.e("AsyncTask", "onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Log.v("AsyncTask", "doInBackground");
            tareaLarga();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            Log.v("AsyncTask", "onPostExecute");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tarea finalizada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

La función `tareaLarga()` es la encargada de cargar los datos en el `Spinner` y funciona bien. si pongo un `Toast` en el `onClick` del `button` sea antes o despues de `mitarea.execute()` el `Toast` se muestra pero el AsyncTask no trabaja, me doy cuenta de esto por los 3 logs y el Toast que puse, ninguno hace nada. Que estoy haciendo mal?

> Actualización

Si se ejecuta el Asynctask pero no carga el Sipnner. el Toast y los logs si se ejecutan

Comment: Buenas @martin-fernandez, en caso de que logres comprobar que tu listado que intentas enviar a tu spinner tenga datos, lo mas probable es que te estaría faltando lo mencionado en la respuesta del usuario Fifer Sheep de la pregunta del siguiente [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283337/how-to-update-a-spinner-dynamically)

Comment: Hola Nicethunder, gracias por tu respuesta. ¿como cierro la pregunta?, es que el problema estaba en que a la base de datos donde estoy consultando los datos de un momento a otro cayo (cuando probé fuera del async funcionaba, cuando probé dentro el servidor se cayo) y me entero 30 minutos después de haber echo la pregunta aquí. Estoy hace 2 horas literal jajaja

Comment: @MartinFernandez el problema es al realizar la consulta:  arrList_obras = conexiones.SELECT("SELECT * FROM OBRAS", getApplicationContext(), 3);  Asegura esta retorne una lista de elementos,de lo contrario no se mostrara nada en tu Adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como esta escrito tu código no debe existir problema en ejecutar el `AsyncTask`, lo debes realizar de esta forma

```
new MitareaAsincrona().execute();
```

el problema es debido seguramente a que la consulta que realizas no retorna una lista de elementos en `arrList_obras`, debes asegurar la consulta obtenga datos para que estos llenen tu `ArrayAdapter` :

```
 private void tareaLarga()
    {
        arrList_obras = conexiones.SELECT("SELECT * FROM OBRAS", getApplicationContext(), 3);
        arrAdapter_obras = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_drawable, arrList_obras);
        spinner_obras.setAdapter(arrAdapter_obras);
    }
```

---

**Actualización:**

Comentas que "si lo hago sin usar la tarea Asincrona si se cargan perfectamente", entonces el problema es al cargar los datos.

Dentro del método  `tareaLarga()` que se realiza dentro de `doInbackground()` del `Asynctask` realiza únicamente la obtención de datos:

```
private void tareaLarga()
    {
        arrList_obras = conexiones.SELECT("SELECT * FROM OBRAS", getApplicationContext(), 3);
    }
```

pero dentro de `onPostExecute()` del `AsyncTask` que es donde muestras los cambios en la UI a partir de los datos obtenidos en `doInbackground()`  , configura tu `Adapter` con los datos

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            Log.v("AsyncTask", "onPostExecute");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tarea finalizada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            arrAdapter_obras = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_drawable, arrList_obras);
            spinner_obras.setAdapter(arrAdapter_obras);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola Jorge estuve haciendo pruebas con datos que no traigo de ningún lugar externo a la aplicación y solo se muestran los Toast y los Logs que hago, pero en cuanto a los Spinner ninguno carga nada. (si lo hago sin usar la tarea Asincrona si se cargan perfectamente) Tendra que ver con el Contexto?

Comment: Con este comentario "si lo hago sin usar la tarea Asincrona si se cargan perfectamente" me he dadocuenta del  detalle, agrego información @MartinFernandez

Comment: El problema era el que indicas exactamente Jorge. A pesar de que el problema se ha solucionado tengo un nuevo inconveniente y es que el Spinner no muestra el item seleccionado (si clickeo dentro muestro el desplegable con toda la informacion), a que se debe?

Comment: ok, que te parece si realizas otra pregunta con esto, si puedes agrega una imagen, ¿te refieres a que desaparece el item seleccionado?

Comment: Voy a hacer eso Jorge, la seguimos en la próxima pregunta

Comment: @MartinFernandez claro que sí saludos!